# Jest SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' in TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, next.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm encountering an issue while running Jest in my TypeScript project. I have a TypeScript file located at rootDir/src/_services/index.ts, and Jest is throwing the following error:

```
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from './auth.service';                                                                                   ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

The content of index.ts includes the statement  `export * from './auth.service';`, and it seems that Jest is having trouble parsing it.
`export * from './auth.service'`

I'm using a custom Jest configuration along with ts-jest. Here is a snippet from my Jest configuration file

````
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
});

const customJestConfig = {
  // ... other configurations ...
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '/@bufbuild/protobuf/',
    '/src/_services/index\\.ts$', // Ignore this path
  ],
  // ... other configurations ...
};
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);```
````

Answer (score 0):

Is that a reason why you included the third element ('/src/_services/index\.ts$') here?:

```js
 transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '/@bufbuild/protobuf/',
    '/src/_services/index\\.ts$', // delete this!
  ],
```

coz it means that your file /src/_services/index.ts will NOT be transformed by any tool and keep its ts syntax.